# How can I inherit from classes I didn't make like requests in python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, python-requests

I am building an object-oriented app that utilizes the requests lib for sending and receiving data from an API, but I can't manage to find out a way to inherit from the requests module. not just for requests but for Tkinter also.

the general problem is that I can't really inherit from classes I didn't make personally like third party lib

All I want to do is just simply say "self.get" or "self.post" .

here is a code example of what I want to do: -

```py
import requests 
class Create(requests):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
      def create(self):
          self.post(url,headers,data)
```

I tried several methods even including modifying the original code of the lib to make classes I can inherit from but it didn't work either

Comment: Yeah, you can't derive from a _module_ (`requests`). It sounds like you want to derive from `requests.Session`...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The problem is that `requests` is *not a class*, therefore it cannot be a base class from which you derive your class. "I tried several methods even including modifying the original code of the lib to make classes I can inherit from but it didn't work either" There *already are* classes present that you can inherit from. You should learn about them by *reading the documentation*.

Comment: @AKX hey, I tried importing from `Session` but it doesn't seem to work either, i think what I need is to find the class that has the get, post, etc methods in and inherit from it but I can't seem to find it

Comment: @KarlKnechtel hey, i tried reading the documentation but all examples I have seen are directly using the methods without indicating what classes they came from

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing special about inheriting from 3rd-party classes, inheritance works just like with your own classes:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.Request
<class 'requests.models.Request'>
>>> class MyRequest(requests.Request):
...  def say_hello(self):
...   print("Hello!")
... 
>>> MyRequest()
<Request [None]>
>>> MyRequest().say_hello()
Hello!
>>>
```

Comment: yes there is no issue with the importing itself but the thing is I want the instance created from my class to have access to the requests methods such as "get" or "post"

Answer (score 0):

With `requests`, you want to derive from `requests.Session`. (The `requests.post`, etc. helpers just build an one-shot session and call the method by the same name.)

Like so:

```
import requests

class MySession(requests.Session):
     base_url = "https://example.com"

     def create(self, data):
         return self.post(f"{self.base_url}/create", json=data)

sess = MySession()
sess.create("hello")  # does a POST to https://example.com/create
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, and it worked thank you very much :))

Comment: but why does when I use that method this happens `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'post'`

Comment: Because you're not using that exact code, but something else that's not working.